# Pipeline working with object id aggregation with $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
Users.aggregate([{ $geoNear: { near: {type: "Point" , coordinates: [lng,lat] } , distanceField: "dist.calculated" , maxDistance: 2000000 ,query: { deleted: '0' , _id: { $ne: user_result._id}}}}, { $lookup: {from: 'images' , let: { user_connected: '$_id' } , pipeline:[ {
                         $match: {
                             $expr:{
                                       $eq: [ "$user" , "$$user_connected" ]
                             }
                         },
                        } ] , as: 'images'}} ,{ $skip: skip },{ $limit: perpage}]).allowDiskUse(true).exec(function (err, result) {
                         if(err) {
                            return res.status(400).json({success: 202 , message: "Database Error." , result: err});
                         }
                       if(isset(result) && !empty(result)){
                         return res.status(200).json({success: 200 , message: "Users Data." , result: result});
                       }else{
                        return res.status(400).json({success: 205 , message: "No Records Found." , result: []});
                       }
                    });
                    
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ImagesSchema = new Schema({
        name: { type: String  , required: true},
        user: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'users' , default: '' }],
        status: { type: String , default: ''} ,
        expireTime: { type:  Date , default: new Date()}
    },
    {timestamps: true})
    //.index({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 86400 });
    console.log("Create Index if collection droped")

var images = mongoose.model('images', ImagesSchema);

module.exports = images;
```

I am creating a pipeline to connect user model to images model but it is not fetching all images from images model. I am connecting my user model to images for showing in users listing but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It should work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, I am not getting an error but the key for images in every record is blank array [] but I have many records in images model for all the users.

Comment: Could you post sample collections from both the documents?

Comment: User: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc6cebd72d46b2ae27da239"),
    "first_name" : "Chetan",
    "last_name" : "",
   }
Images: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc70b56ec3cb92e9999b8be"),
    "user" : [ 
        ObjectId("5bc6cebd72d46b2ae27da239")
    ],
    "status" : "image1",
    "expireTime" : ISODate("2018-10-17T10:00:53.363Z"),
    "name" : "3079542441568image_Ember_5bc6be625a753e21eb84529f_101718154340.jpeg",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-10-17T10:13:42.223Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-17T10:13:42.223Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: Try this `{
                         $match: {
                             $expr:{
                                       $in: [  "$$user_connected","$user" ]
                             }
                         }
                        }`

Comment: I tried but still, I don't get any result.

Comment: I have tested them with your above documents. It gives me the desired result.

Comment: Okay but it is not working I tried but can't get the desired result. Have any idea??